# VBA/Excel: Not accepting SQL subclauses

Tags: vba, excel, oracle10g, common-table-expression

I have an Excel/VBA spreadsheet connecting to an Oracle database via ADODB. The connection works fine and ordinary queries run fine. But I'm trying to be a little bit clever and avoid running multiple select statements by using a `with as` clause. This link basically explains what I'm trying to do:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

My SQL works fine when it's run directly without Excel. However Excel/VBA has a problem with the `With As` clause and throws up a "Run-Time error '3704'; Application-defined or object-defined" error . This is a reduced version of my SQL and code:

SQL

```
with ORDERED as (select
start_value, country
from
MYTABLE
where country = '840') select * from ORDERED
```

VBA Code

```
Dim dbaRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim gloDatabase As ADODB.Connection
dim sSQL as string

sSQL = "with ORDERED as (select start_value, country from MYTABLE where      country = '840') select * from ORDERED"
Set gloDatabase = New ADODB.Connection
gloDatabase.ConnectionString = My_Connection_String
gloDatabase.Open
gloDatabase.CursorLocation = adUseClient  

Set dbaRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
dbaRecordSet.ActiveConnection = DBConnection
dbaRecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
dbaRecordSet.Source = sSQL
dbaRecordSet.Open
```

Does anyone know why Excel/VBA is refusing to accept the `With As ()` clause? If I remove the clause and run it as an ordinary `select` statement, everything works fine. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Can you please add the runtime error that you receive? It could help people answer this question, and help future visitors find the question.

Comment: Its " Run-Time error '3704'; Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Awesome. Edit that into your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write nested select statement a bit differently inside VBA. Try

```
select * from (
    select
        start_value, country
    from
        MYTABLE
    where country = '840'
) ORDERED
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a temp table instead of the With As clause?

```
select start_value, country
into #TempTable
from MYTABLE where country = '840'

Select * from #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```